# Binding reference DataTemplate from within another DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to bind a command from a DataTemplate outside my DataTemplate.

The Command `InfoButtonCommand` is in my `AppSettingsPageViewModel` and i can't find a way to bind it to my button.

```xml
<DataTmplate DataType="{x:Type wizard:AppSettingsPageViewModel}"  x:Name="AppSettingsPageDataTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid>
            <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding AppSettingsConf, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Key" Header="Key" ReadOnly="True"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Value" Header="Value" />
                <dxg:GridColumn>
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <!-- The Command Binding -->
                            <Button Content="ClickMe" Command="{
                                Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType={x:Type DataTemplate}}, Path=InfoButtonCommand}">
                            </Button>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I tried binding via the DataTemplates Type

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding Path=InfoButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wizard:AppSettingsPageViewModel}}, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

direct Binding:

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding InfoButtonCommand}">
```

via Name:

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=AppSettingsPageDataTemplate, Path=InfoButtonCommand}">
```

But none of the above seemed to work. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why didn't they work? Any error messages you could add to your question with an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57495190/edit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct AncestorType in this case will be `AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridControl}`

the command can be obtained by `Path=DataContext.InfoButtonCommand`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wizard:AppSettingsPageViewModel}"  x:Name="AppSettingsPageDataTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid>
            <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding AppSettingsConf, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Key" Header="Key" ReadOnly="True"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Value" Header="Value" />
                <dxg:GridColumn>
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <!-- The Command Binding -->
                            <Button Content="ClickMe" 
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridControl}}, Path=DataContext.InfoButtonCommand}">
                            </Button>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this and mm8's answer worked for me!